# To what does the byte sequence in this kerneloops (syslogd@hostname) message refer?

Tags: kernel, syslog

```
Message from syslogd@ROOROO at Mar 22 19:36:12 ...
 kernel:[13988.165672] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 

Message from syslogd@ROOROO at Mar 22 19:36:12 ...
 kernel:[13988.169607] Stack:

Message from syslogd@ROOROO at Mar 22 19:36:12 ...
 kernel:[13988.169607] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@ROOROO at Mar 22 19:36:12 ...
 kernel:[13988.169607] Code: 55 53 48 81 ec 88 00 00 00 48 8b af 28 03 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 78 31 c0 8b 05 00 bb 07 00 48 89 7c 24 48 <4c> 8b 7d 08 c1 e8 15 83 e0 07 83 f8 03 76 43 48 8b 8d 78 02 00 

Message from syslogd@ROOROO at Mar 22 19:36:12 ...
 kernel:[13988.169607] CR2: 0000000000000008
```

I've been running my latest Debian testing netbook for about 2 months.

This is the first kernel failure that has flooded my always-open terminal emulator.

I am asking about the bytes that come after `Code:` and am just curious about what they may mean, and why they have flooded my terminal emulator as a normal user.

Comment: Do you have a similar, but more readable, message in `/var/log/syslog` or `messages` ?

Comment: The bytes look like machine code.

This looks like either defective hardware or some bad driver which causes the kernel to oops. Do you get any misbehaviour (e.g. crashes, freezes) when this happens?

Comment: We'd need the full trace to say anything. The bytes are specific to a particular compiled kernel and are meaningless if you aren't following the code in a debugger.

Comment: @Gilles so are you saying that unless I can reproduce this kerneloops reliably (while running, what, gdb? on what process? with what args?), there's no way to know anything about that byte sequence?